# Which wire is the positive and which the negative on this fan?

Tags: fan

Here is link with the picture of the fan:

[image]

The fan name is "ZALMAN ZM-F3(SF) 120MM ULTRA QUIET FAN"

I looked it up online, but I don't understand, I'm colourblind and it's difficult to distinguish the colors.

Comment: We can take educated guesses, but it's impossible to know without knowing where that fan connected to! If it's just a PC fan, you can certainly look up "PC fan pinout" ;)

Comment: Well, the wires are black and white, so color isn't a problem.  It's a PC fan, so look up how they are wire.  That's a keyed connector, so you can find pin 1 if you match it to a drawing.

Comment: The linked (and closed) duplicate shows you the connections.  You don't need the colors.  Look at where the pins are in relation to the shape of the connector.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice black-and-white illustration that shows the pinout of

- 3 pin connectors (so-called DC fans), to the left
- 4 pin connectors (PWM controlled fans), to the right

[image: PC fan header pinout]

(Image from [here](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/577726-pwm-fan-speed-cant-be-set-to-less-than-50/).)

See also [the duplicate post linked in the comments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/which-wire-is-negative-on-this-pc-fan).